# Exchange online can I get a list of all mailboxes

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I need to get a list of all mailboxes.

Can I get this list with EWS and PowerShell?

Exchange online shell will not be installed on the server where I run the script.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Maybe you can still use Basic authentication method if you don't have MFA enabled on the connecting account. However, don't count on that working forever. You could try [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PowerShell you can just simple call the **Get-MailBox** powershell command.
[image]

This is working for on-premise and O365 mailboxes as well. For O365 environment sooner or later you will need to transfer to modern authentication, but basic authentication will still work for a while. This is the easier way of I can think of.

Based on my knowledge it's not possible to list all mailboxes using entirely with EWS.